# embedded linux kernel distribution

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, embedded-linux

I am doing embedded system development with my EVM board. And now, i want to release my whole software to others. To get some referrences on how to package my software, i downloaded some other vendors' linux SDK.
The thing confused me is if its vendor modified the linux kernel, instead of releasing the SDK with a dirty kernel directly they all have a original clean kernel along with a patch containing this modification.
So,that is why?  To avoid license? Linux kernel license requires the kernel not be spreaded with personal modification?
Thanks

Comment: The Linux kernel uses the GPL2 license, so it is permitted to distribute modified sources. The separate patch file is to make it easier to see what was changed, and also allows the patch to be applied to updated kernels, at least in the same "stable" series.

Comment: "Legal questions, including questions about copyright or licensing, are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Open Source Stack Exchange or Law Stack Exchange may be suitable alternatives." https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic